# Can't access projects in wamp

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

While I am trying to access my projects on WAMP Server it shows no internet connection.
I already tried to restart my WAMP and system, remove Skype and finally I reinstalled WAMP Server but no use.
Please provide a solution.

Comment: how you access your project - link ? is your wamp server running,  wamp icon color is green?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdqfA4ACob4

Answer (score 0):

Wamp Server localhost not working. problems port 80 is closed. Icon Color Yellow

**Solution:**

wamp icon click > Apache > Service > Service Install

wamp icon click > All Services Restart

Icon Green its Work

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdqfA4ACob4